# Retrieve post info within AJAX helper function

Tags: jquery, ajax, front-end

I have a button within a post which a user can click. Once clicked, an AJAX call is made.

My question is, within my PHP AJAX helper function (located in my theme's function.php) how can I retrieve, for instance, the ID of the post that the request was sent from.

I can get the ID from the markup and pass it in the AJAX call but it seems messy, i.e.

```
<article id="post-12">
<!-- article content -->
</article>


// JS
var postID = $("article").attr("id");
```

Is there a better way? Some kind of global that is accessible perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to declare globals.

**Example:**

```
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

You could store your query results there and access them later.

Comment: The issue there is that the variable is being stored in the mark-up, meaning that anyone that knows how to use firebug can modify the variable and send bogus requests to my helper function.

Comment: @aprea You can a) use a nonce within localize script and check this in the post which you then check back in your cb fn and b) you can assign anything (but a more dim. js-array) to the localized object.

Comment: @kaiser nonce only makes sense if users are registered.

Comment: @aprea You'll have to validate your result anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If this is within the loop, you can use `the_ID()` or `get_the_ID()` and pass the value. I don't see how a helper function can know what the post is unless you tell it explicitly.